# React Native Facebook login button crashes app in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbsdk

I am trying to set up Facebook login in my React Native iOS app using FBSDK. The button renders but when clicked crashes the app in the iOS simulator. It doesn't even console log any errors in the remote debugger.

I added the FBSDKCoreKit.framework and FBSDKLoginKit.framework to my project in xcode and followed [this guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/installing-the-facebook-sdk-into-a-react-native-android-and-ios-app-69439bd97a99#.j01ieh68a) on how to modify my `info.plist` and `AppDelegate.m`

Is there something wrong with my code for the button?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import FBSDK from 'react-native-fbsdk'
const { LoginButton } = FBSDK    

import styles from '../styles'    

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.onLoginFinished = this.onLoginFinished.bind(this)
  }    

  onLoginFinished (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      alert("Login failed with error: " + error);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert("Login was cancelled");
    } else {
      alert("Login was successful with permissions: " + result)
    }
  }    

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}> 
        <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={["public_profile"]}
          onLoginFinished={this.onLoginFinished}
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

***Edit***

Adding logs from running `react-native log-ios` per comment from Andreyco

```
 <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Read permissions are not permitted to be requested with publish or manage permissions.'
  *** First throw call stack:
  (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102ce34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f1dc21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102ce299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   FunDates                            0x000000010e860c05 -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:fromViewController:handler:] + 228
    4   FunDates                            0x000000010e85d523 -[FBSDKLoginButton _buttonPressed:] + 1662
    5   UIKit                               0x000000011284b5b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001129d0edd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001129d11f6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001129d00f2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001128b8ce1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001128ba3cf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x000000011286763f -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011305971d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001130523c7 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110273311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011025859c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110257a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110257494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000116095a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000112849964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  FunDates                            0x000000010e69f9bf main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011421668d start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
  )
```

Comment: run `react-native log-ios` to tail logs from device. Post logs then

Comment: @Andreyco logs added

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I needed to change `publishPermissions` to `readPermissions`

```
<LoginButton
  readPermissions={["public_profile email"]}
  onLoginFinished={this.loginFinished.bind(this)}
  onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}
/>
```

Comment: @plmok61 I'm encountering the same error but changing `public` to `read` didn't work for me. Any other ideas that you might have ran into since this post?

Comment: Thank you!! The FB documentation didn't bother with this small detail...

Comment: Look no further - this is what you need.

Comment: Wow.  I wonder if there's any reason for this oversight in the docs?  Does Facebook still consider this SDK the preferred-path?

Comment: You saved couple of hours for me at the least! Thanks a ton!